# How do I tell react to go straight to an nginx proxy pass?

Tags: reactjs, nginx

I have a path in my react app called `/help/123/doc` that I do not want to render through the react app. I want it to bypass the app and go straight to the nginx proxy pass:

```
location /help/([0-9]+)/doc {
    resolver 1.1.1.1;
    proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin;
    proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Methods;
    proxy_hide_header X-Frame-Options;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $http_true_client_ip;
    set $pp_1 https://someothersite.com/api$uri;
    proxy_pass $pp_1;
}
```

How should I achieve that? I have used the following but they are not doing much (pathname is `/help/123/doc`):

```
return <Redirect to={{ pathname: pathname }} />;
return <Link to={{ pathname: pathname }} />;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `return window.open('your-url/help.123/doc')`

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open for documentation